How to handle differentiate between constrain errors in SQLAlchemy?
Take a look at sample code below:
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass, Mapped, mapped_column, Session
from typing import Annotated
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

database = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
engine = create_engine(database, echo=True)
session = Session(engine)


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    name: Mapped[Annotated[str, 20]] = mapped_column(unique=True)
    email: Mapped[Annotated[str, 320]]  = mapped_column(unique=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    u1 = User(name='xyz',email='abcd@email.com')
    u2 = User(name='xyz',email='foo@email.com') 
     
    session.add(u1)
    session.add(u2)
    
    try:
        session.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        print('=======================================================================================')
        print(str(e).split('\n')) # access notes as well
        print('-----------------------------')
        print(e.args)
        
        # but how do I know which table constrain is failed?

The user table contains two unique constraints, This document suggests that some DBAPI errors are wrappers around errors that are specified at PEP-249. Also the sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError originates from the database driver (DBAPI), not SQLAlchemy itself.
Thus I read the documentation for IntegrityError at PEP-249. But that also doesn't seem to help.
So, long story short: How to know in code which "type of" constraints failed and for which column? For example how you distinguish between different errors based on status code in HTTP.

Does this answer your question?

This is the exact question I wanted to ask. Thank you @snakecharmerb
